# VBA subscript out of range, code 9

Tags: excel, vba

I'm conducting my very first VBA macro and I'm having some difficulties with this seemingly easy code to read data from a closed workbook into my currently opened one.

```
Sub KAuto()

   Dim path As String
   path = "C:\files\Utfall.xlsx"
   Dim currentWb As Workbook
   Set currentWb = ThisWorkbook
   Dim openWb As Workbook
   Set openWb = Workbooks.Open(path)
   Dim openWs As Worksheet
   Set openWs = openWb.Sheets("March")
   currentWb.Sheets("Indata").Range("A1").Value = openWs.Range("A3").Value
End Sub
```

The problem I'm having is that I get a code 9, subscript out of range. But I've checked that A1 and A3 is existent for the current workbook and the imported one respectively.

What I have tried to do is to omit the ".Value" in all combinations, as that was what the original author did.

Googling this problem I've encountered that people misused functions which I do not use, for instance windows(), or omitted "" for referencing the worksheets, or  simply misspelled things. I don't Think I have any of these, and so I need further help.

How can I correct my subscript out of range? Is there a better way to achieve this copying of cells? In the future I want to import 10 files, will this then be obsolete? (I recall someone posting something in the lines of openWb = [file1,file2,file3] and looping through them, but I cannot find it; does anyone have a link?

EDIT: I've copied the path to the file from its properties, so it ought to be correct.

EDIT2:

```
  currentWb.Sheets("Indata").Range("A1").Value = openWs.Range("A3").Value
```

snippet gives the error

EDIT3: VB editor print screen:

[image: VBA editor print screen]

Comment: on which line does it give the error ?

Comment: @guarav5430 Thanks for reply, its at " currentWb.Sheets("Indata").Range("A1").Value = openWs.Range("A3").Value"

Comment: have you checked that the current wrokbook has a sheet named "Indata" . or may be you are running it while the other workbook is active?

Comment: Yes it does. However I've seen now that I have the sub KAuto, which I can find through Tools->Macros. However at the top of my current VBA Project ti says:
"Kal.xla.xls", can this cause problems? I've tried to rename it but I can't find a "save as" but only a save

Comment: i dont think it might cause this error, but you may as well try saving it with correct name. to enable "save as" --> go to menu options (a little downarrow) --> more commands --> save as or use keyboard shortcut Alt+F2

Comment: In which workbook is the `KAuto` sub located? Is it the same as the one that has a sheet called "Indata"? Because that's the only possible source of this particular error.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett I'm not sure about this actually. When I open my workbook called "Workbookxy" and press Alt + F11 then I have KAuto there, and I run it. Is that what you mean? Should I rename KAuto to Workbookxy as well to "include" KAuto sub into the workbook?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett Added an print screen now.

Comment: I see you have a *sub* named `KAuto`, which is in a *module* which happens to also be called "KAuto". Where is this module located? Can you find it in the project explorer on the left? What workbook is it in? Looks like it isn't in "Workbookxy"...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett Thanks for your reply! It seems as it is in one of the company's default workbooks for addins etc. I reckon that changing this would render the code feasible. How do you "select" which workbook to put your module in? I thought that opening the Workbook and using Alt + F11 would solve that for you, since that's been the impression I've gotten from all the tutorials. "Do this, and it will work"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `ActiveWorkbook` instead of `ThisWorkbook`.

```
Set currentWb = ActiveWorkbook
```

[`ThisWorkbook`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193227.aspx) refers to the workbook in which the code resides. [`ActiveWorkbook`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821871.aspx) refers to the workbook that is currently active i.e. "on top" in the Excel application. It looks like your case, the code resides in a different workbook; so what you want is `ActiveWorkbook`.

And you *can* ommit the `.value` from last line.

`currentWb.Sheets("Indata").Range("A1") = openWs.Range("A3")`

Your code worked fine for me, that`s why I cannot be sure if it will help. 
<strike>There can be an issue, when opening the openWs. The *error line* can be evaluated before the openWs is actually open. Then maybe add a line :</strike>

```
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")) 'this is 3 seconds from now
```

**after** the `Set openWb = Workbooks.Open(path)`.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Must go from the office now but will try that as soon as I get back. If it works for you but not me, may I lack some requisite or something?

Comment: Added those lines and got "Automation fault '-2147221080 (800401a8)

Comment: Did you try the code *without* the `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))` first? Just switching from `ThisWorkbook` to `ActiveWorkbook`?

Comment: Thanks! This works! Have any idea as to whether it does not work with Application.Wait? Or why ActiveWorkbook works but not ThisWorkbook. Does ThisWorkbook reference in the way that Jean-François Corbett  saw that I've done wrong, whereas ActiveWorkbook does not need this reference? Thanks again!

Comment: Exactly, you were on a good track there. `ThisWorkbook` is a workbook, where the code is running from. You have put it into the addin workbook and there it cannot find the `.Sheets("Indata")`. Hence the error. `ActiveWorkbook` on the other hand is run from currently active workbook, the one that has "focus", so it will work, because there is the sheet `.Sheets("Indata")`. I would still recomend **NOT** putting your code into the AddIn workbook, but into your own *Workbookxy* into separate module. As for the `Application.Wait` I dont know, but that was a wild guess. Dont worry abou that. :)

Comment: Does this practice of putting code into workbooks etc have a name, or is it called something? Haven't read of this, but reckon I really should read some documentation or something on the matter.

Comment: I don't know about any specific term that applies to this practice. I learned it the *same way you did*. Trial and error. It is easy to overlook where you are putting your code. You will just have to pay attention. That's all. Good luck.

Comment: I will definitely pay more attention to this! Thanks again!

Comment: I took the liberty of adding some documentation to this answer, to explain what's going on.